# Why this code can not change(lower) the integrity level of the file?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have written the code to change the integrity level of an object(not a process)(in this case a file). As we know we start up with Medium integirty level but I want to lower it to "Low". I want to run a .txt file with low integrity instead of default medium.

I'm using a WINAPI mostly for this purpouses. So I created a .txt file to lower its integrity from medium to low.

```
void SetLowLabelToFile()
{
    int k = 0;
    // The LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION SDDL SACL to be set for low integrity 
#define LOW_INTEGRITY_SDDL_SACL_W L"S:(ML;;NW;;;LW)"
    DWORD dwErr = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;

    PACL pSacl = NULL; // not allocated
    BOOL fSaclPresent = FALSE;
    BOOL fSaclDefaulted = FALSE;
    LPCWSTR pwszFileName = L"C:\\Users\\Dan\\Documents\\testIntegrity\\hi1.txt";

    if (ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW(
        LOW_INTEGRITY_SDDL_SACL_W, SDDL_REVISION_1, &pSD, NULL))
    {
        k = GetLastError();
        if (GetSecurityDescriptorSacl(pSD, &fSaclPresent, &pSacl,
            &fSaclDefaulted))
        {
            k = GetLastError();

            // Note that psidOwner, psidGroup, and pDacl are 
            // all NULL and set the new LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION
            dwErr = SetNamedSecurityInfoW((LPWSTR)pwszFileName,
                SE_FILE_OBJECT, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                NULL, NULL, NULL, pSacl);
            k = GetLastError();

        }
        LocalFree(pSD);
    }
}
```

I set up 3 GetLastErrors to get an error-code and the last one is 1008. This means that `An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist`. I didn't get it because the way to the file is valid. Could anyone please help to solve the problem?

Comment: you incorrect use GetLastError() - in wrong place. if ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW and GetSecurityDescriptorSacl return true - call GetLastError() - no sense. the SetNamedSecurityInfoW at all not set GetLastError() but direct return error code. except this - your code correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data files don't have integrity levels.  Processes have integrity levels.

You can't "run a .txt file", you run an "application" that then *loads* the `.txt` file. The "application" would have to be run at a low integrity level, not the `.txt` file itself.

The correct way to launch a low-integrity process from your code is to:

- Have your code duplicate its current process handle using `OpenProcessToken()` and `DuplicateTokenEx()`.
- Use `SetTokenInformation()` to set the integrity level in that access token to Low.
- Use `CreateProcessAsUser()` to create a new process using that Low integrity access token.

There is an example of this (in C#) on MSDN:

[Create low-integrity process in C# (CSCreateLowIntegrityProcess)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSCreateLowIntegrityProcess-d7cb5e4d)

Comment: ,Thanks for your answer, but what is this about? [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7f00f95a-e237-457d-bcfa-2931bf778fd5/how-to-change-file-integrity-level-using-c?forum=windowssecurity)

Comment: *Data files don't have integrity levels* - yes, but any object which have security descriptor can have integrity **label** in SACL. and we can set it

Comment: another way - create process in suspended state with `CreateProcess`, open it token, set low integrity level, and resume

Comment: A [mandatory label](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-system_mandatory_label_ace) in the SACL sets the *integrity level* of an object. Implicitly objects are at medium integrity level if they are not labeled. This is a basic component of mandatory access control, in combination with a token's integrity level and [mandatory policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-token_mandatory_policy). The linked example depends on this to demonstrate that a low integrity process can write to `LocalAppDataLow` but not to `LocalAppData`.

Comment: Note the "new-process-min" rule in the mandatory policy results in spawning a process at a lower integrity level than the parent if the executable is at a lower level. This policy is set for standard logons, in which case running a low-integrity executable from a medium-integrity standard logon will spawn a low-integrity process. This policy is not set typically for high-integrity (elevated) logons, however, and the policy cannot be modified for an in-use primary token.

Comment: Please fix your first two sentences. All secured objects have an integrity level that's either implicitly medium level or set by a [label](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-system_mandatory_label_ace) in the SACL of the object's security descriptor. This includes the security of Process objects and Token objects. In this regard a Token object has two integrity levels, the level of the object itself in its security descriptor, plus the integrity-level SID in the groups of the Token that's used for mandatory access checks in combination with its mandatory policy.